# sum two lists element-by-element in python recursively

Tags: python, arrays, list, recursion

Is it possible to recursively sum two lists element by element and then return the new list?

```
def sumListElements(listOne, listTwo):
    list = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(listOne):
        list.append(listOne[i] + listTwo[i])
        i += 1
    return list
```

So,

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [3, 4, 5]
```

Results

```
R = [4, 6, 8]
```

Comment: Why recursive? You have no nested structure here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a recursive implementation

```
def recursive_sum(l1, l2, idx = 0):
    if idx < min(len(l1), len(l2)):
        return [l1[idx] + l2[idx]] + recursive_sum(l1, l2, idx + 1)
    else:
        return []

print recursive_sum([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
# [5, 7, 9]
```

Or

```
def recursive_sum(l1, l2, result = None, idx = 0):
    if result is None:
        result = []
    if idx < min(len(l1), len(l2)):
        result.append(l1[idx] + l2[idx])
        return recursive_sum(l1, l2, result, idx + 1)
    else:
        return result
```

Comment: @Xerath Make sure to site this answer in your homework...

Answer (score 2):

Use `zip()` and `map()` here:

```
R = map(sum, zip(a, b))
```

Demo:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [3, 4, 5]
>>> map(sum, zip(a, b))
[4, 6, 8]
```

For Python 3 compatibility, replace `map()` with a list comprehension:

```
[sum(z) for z in zip(a, b)]
```

Comment: So, that's the only way to do this ?

Comment: No, this is the most efficient way to do it.

Comment: I like the efficient way, but I have to write it recursively, just like @thefourtheye is done.

Answer (score 1):

Function which takes n lists, and adds each element in an i-th index together with the others:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

def sum_elements(*lists):
    return map(sum, izip_longest(*lists, fillvalue=0))
```

Showed with your data:

```
>>> sum_elements([1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5])
[4, 6, 8]
```

Lists with uneven lengths still have a nice result:

```
>>> sum_elements([1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5, 6])
[4, 6, 8, 6]
```

And it can take any number of lists:

```
>>> sum_elements([1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5, 6], [8,9])
[12, 15, 8, 6]
```